# Easy ERD Program for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need an ERD Program for design my database in MySql.

I tried :

- DBDesigner
- MySql Workbench

The program should be able to export a sql script

In Oracle i just JDeveloper. It was very easy.

What programs do you prefer?

Comment: @Zoidberg - If you are asking it's because you've never tried it yourself...

Comment: @Alvaro - I just wanted to know what was wrong with it.  I have used it myself and I have not had many issues.  However, I am interested in knowing what type of limitations that this person may have found.  So excuse me for keeping an open mind.

Comment: @Zoidberg - Well, basically: 1) Graphs look terrible when you have many tables 2) The synch with DB feature is full of bugs and limitations 3) It's crashing all the time.

Comment: @Alvaro See, I have never had those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use MySQL Workbench, or I draw it out by hand. After that it's generally super simple for me to create a database in a matter of minutes (depending on the size).

That said, a simple google search brought me to [this page](http://oldresources.visual-paradigm.com/vpsuite2.2sp2/generate_sql.html), so the program attached to that website might be worth checking out.

Comment: I use it in a similar way.  I find it to be a nice tool for getting your thoughts down on paper (so to speak).

Comment: Yeah. It's a good way to connect the interface with how the actual DB setup is going to be. In the process you may even find a few things you missed or implement new rules to make the system better as well.